# What's the problem with my C LANGUAGE code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50, substitution

Hey I'm a begginer at coding and have a little problem with my code and it would be good of you to help me in it.
Would really like your advice.

In this problem which is problem set 2 of **CS50** file **Substitution**
we have to get a key and the text from the user in which the output should be the letter at the place at which the letter is available in the **alphabetical order**.

INPUT:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char *key;
    char *normal = get_string("NORMAL: ");
    char *coded = malloc(sizeof(normal));

    do{
        /*Asking for key*/
        key = get_string("KEY: ");
    } while(strlen(key) != 26);

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(normal); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < strlen(normal); j++)
        {
            if(normal[i] < 91  && normal[i] > 64)
            {
                if(normal[i] == (65 + j))
                {
                    coded[i] = toupper(key[j]);
                }
            }
            else if(normal[i] < 123 && normal[i] > 96)
            {
                if(normal[i] == (97 + j))
                {
                    coded[i] = tolower(key[j]);
                }
            }
            else (coded[i] = normal[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("Coded: %s", coded);
}
```

They show me the **segmentation fault error** and I don't know at which place have i touched the wrong memory.

Comment: "*I don't know at which place have i touched the wrong memory*". Then it's a perfect time to learn to use a debugger. A debugger will instantly tell you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. It can also be used to examine the program flow and variable values as it runs.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(normal));` That is wrong. `sizeof(normal)` will give the size of the pointer. You probably want `malloc(strlen(normal)+1)`.

Comment: You gotta love the cs50 library, and the subtle, yet dreadful, memory leak resulting from that opening do-while loop. Regarding your code, start by stopping all the magic-number usage.

Comment: @WhozCraig cs50 is terrible in so many ways. They have implemented the library such that it will free all the memory in the destructor. Teaching a whole generation of devs not to think about memory management in C - what could go wrong?

Comment: @kaylum I wanna find the pinhead grad-student that first proffered that abomination  and pop them square in the nose. That thing is a steaming pile. Generations of engineers learned C without it (thankfully). It is a textbook definition of some elitist forcing a "solution" upon a population where there isn't a problem to begin with.

Comment: @WhozCraig lemme guess - get_string() mallocs its output buffer pointer:(

Comment: @MartinJames Yup. And it took ~130 lines of code to do it. Hunt it down (and kill it if you can) on the web. You'll see. So smart, eh? I especially liked the comment "but library's destructor frees memory on program's exit" - Terrific. Know what else frees that memory ? Program exit. <facepalm>.